# Changing gain of audio data in objective C results in messed up waveform

Tags: objective-c, audio, signal-processing

So I'm working on processing audio with Objective C, and am attempting to write a gain change function. I have limited the accepted audio formats to 16-bit AIFF files only for now. The process I am using is straightforward: I grab the audio data from my AIFF object, I skip to the point in the audio where I want to process (if x1: 10 and x2: 20 the goal is to change the amplitude of the samples from 10 seconds into the audio to 20 seconds in), and then step through the samples applying the gain change through multiplication. The problem is after I write the processed samples to a new NSMutableData, and then write a new AIFF file using the sound data, the processed samples are completely messed up, and the audio is basically just noise.

```
-(NSMutableData *)normalizeAIFF:(AIFFAudio *)audio x1:(int)x1 x2:(int)x2{

    // obtain audio data bytes from AIFF object
    SInt16 * bytes = (SInt16 *)[audio.ssndData bytes];
    NSUInteger length = [audio.ssndData length] / sizeof(SInt16);

    NSMutableData *newAudio = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    int loudestSample = [self findLoudestSample:audio.ssndData];

    // skip offset and blocksize in SSND data and proceed to user selected point
    // For 16 bit, 44.1 audio, each second of sound data holds 88.2 thousand samples
    int skipTo = 4 + (x1 * 88200);
    int processChunk = ((x2 - x1) * 88200) + skipTo;

    for(int i = skipTo; i < processChunk; i++){
        // convert to float format for processing
        Float32 sampleFloat = (Float32)bytes[i];
        sampleFloat = sampleFloat / 32768.0;
        // This is where I would change the amplitude of the sample
        // sampleFloat = sampleFloat + (sampleFloat * 0.5);

        // make sure not clipping
        if (sampleFloat > 1.0){
            sampleFloat = 1.0;
        } else if (sampleFloat < -1.0){
            sampleFloat = -1.0;
        }

        // convert back to SInt16
        sampleFloat = sampleFloat * 32768.0;
        if (sampleFloat > 32767.0){
            sampleFloat = 32767.0;
        } else if (sampleFloat < -32768.0){
            sampleFloat = -32768.0;
        }

        bytes[i] = (SInt16)sampleFloat;
    }

    [newAudio appendBytes:bytes length:length];

    return newAudio;

}
```

Where in this process could I be going wrong? Is it converting the sample from SInt16 -> float -> SInt16? Printing the data before during and after this conversion seems to show that there is nothing going wrong there. It seems to be after I pack it back into an NSMutableData object, but I'm not too sure.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I also want to mention when I send audio through this function and set the change gain factor to 0 such that the resulting waveform is identical to the input, there are no issues. The waveform comes out looking and sounding exactly the same. It is only when the change gain factor is set to a value that actually changes the samples.

EDIT2: I changed the code to use a pointer and a type cast rather than memcpy(). I still am getting weird results when multiplying the floating point representation of the sample by any number. When I multiply the sample as an SInt16 by an integer I get the proper result, though. This leads me to believe my problem lies in the way I am going about floating point arithmetic. Is there anything anyone sees with the floating point equation I commented out that could be leading to errors?

Comment: You really want to add 0.008 dB of gain? That's not very much.

Comment: Suggestion: Really re-tink the code, there are probably three times as many statements as needed. Using `memcpy()` is not the way to access two bytes, only a pointer and a cast is needed. More code means mo complicated. Check if the data is little or big endian.

Comment: The adding of 0.008 dB of gain is arbitrary...I was just trying any number to get a result and even this little amount was resulting in noise. I have checked the endianness of the data and have been taking it into account while writing the code. I'll look into using a pointer and a cast. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be an endianness issue as Zaph alluded to. I thought I was handling the conversion of big-endian to little-endian correctly when I was not. Now the code looks like:

```
-(NSMutableData *)normalizeAIFF:(AIFFAudio *)audio x1:(int)x1 x2:(int)x2{

    // obtain audio data bytes from AIFF object
    SInt16 * bytes = (SInt16 *)[audio.ssndData bytes];
    NSUInteger length = [audio.ssndData length];

    NSMutableData *newAudio = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    // skip offset and blocksize in SSND data and proceed to user selected point
    // For 16 bit, 44.1 audio, each second of sound data holds 88.2 thousand samples
    int skipTo = 4 + (x1 * 88200);
    int processChunk = ((x2 - x1) * 88200) + skipTo;

    for(int i = skipTo; i < processChunk; i++){

        SInt16 sample = CFSwapInt16BigToHost(bytes[i]);
        bytes[i] = CFSwapInt16HostToBig(sample * 0.5);
    }

    [newAudio appendBytes:bytes length:length];

    return newAudio;

}
```

The gain change factor of 0.5 will change, and I still have to actually normalize the data in relation to the sample with the greatest amplitude in the selection, but the issue I had is solved. When writing the new waveform out to a file it sounds and looks as expected.